# external animated jquery not working--php

Tags: php, jquery, external

I have a main php file that loads an external php file. This is the code in my main php file:

```
<php>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/php; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />


    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />

        <script src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<link href="jimgMenukwicks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js"></script>       

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $().ready(function() {
    $('.jimgMenu ul').kwicks({max: 310, duration: 300, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
    });
</script>


</head>


<div id="tengah" class="jimgMenu" >

  <ul>
    <li class="landscapes"> <a href="javascript:ajaxpage('7.php', 'ResponseDiv');"> </a></li>
    <li class="people"> <a href="javascript:ajaxpage('8.php', 'ResponseDiv');"> </a></li>
    <li class="nature"> <a href="javascript:ajaxpage('9.php', 'ResponseDiv');"> </a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
    <div id="content" class="clearfix shadow">
        <div id="sidebar" class="left">

<div id='ResponseDiv'> </div>
            <div id="menu" class="inner">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main" class="right">
        <h2>Detail</h2>

        <div id='ResponseDiv2'> </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</php>
```

I have a function in `ajax.js` that calls an external php page named `ajaxpage`. Here the code in `ajax.js`:

```
function ajaxpage(url, containerid) {
    var page_request = false
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
    page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) { // if IE
        try {
            page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            } catch(e) {}
        }
    } else return false
    page_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        loadpage(page_request, containerid)
    }
    page_request.open('GET', url, true)
    page_request.send(null)
}

function loadpage(page_request, containerid) {
    if(page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1)) document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML = page_request.responseText
}
```

The problem is when I try to load "7.php" into my main.php the 7.php file is loaded but the animation in 7.php not working.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

this is the content of 7.php

```
<php>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: #0F0D0D;
    padding: 30px 0 0 50px;
}
div.sc_menu_wrapper {
    position: relative;     
    height: 500px;
    /* Make bigger than a photo, because we need a place for a scrollbar. */
    width: 160px;

    margin-top: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}
div.sc_menu {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.sc_menu a {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 130px;

    border: 2px rgb(79, 79, 79) solid;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;        

    /* When image support is turned off */
    color: #fff;
    background: rgb(79, 79, 79);    
}
.sc_menu a:hover {
    border-color: rgb(130, 130, 130);
    border-style: dotted;
}
.sc_menu img {
    display: block;
    border: none;
}

.sc_menu_wrapper .loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 10px;

    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;

    width: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;    

    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    background: #1F1D1D;
}
/* Styling tooltip */
.sc_menu_tooltip {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;

    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 12px;    
    color: #fff;

    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;    

    border: 1px solid rgb(79, 79, 79);
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* Make background a bit transparent for browsers that support rgba */  
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

/* Here are styles for a link to an article. Not for you :) */
#back {
    margin-left: 8px;
    color: gray;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#back:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/

function makeScrollable(wrapper, scrollable){
    // Get jQuery elements
    var wrapper = $(wrapper), scrollable = $(scrollable);

    // Hide images until they are not loaded
    scrollable.hide();
    var loading = $('<div class="loading">Loading...</div>').appendTo(wrapper);

    // Set function that will check if all images are loaded
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        var images = scrollable.find('img');
        var completed = 0;

        // Counts number of images that are succesfully loaded
        images.each(function(){
            if (this.complete) completed++; 
        });

        if (completed == images.length){
            clearInterval(interval);
            // Timeout added to fix problem with Chrome
            setTimeout(function(){

                loading.hide();
                // Remove scrollbars    
                wrapper.css({overflow: 'hidden'});                      

                scrollable.slideDown('slow', function(){
                    enable();   
                });                 
            }, 1000);   
        }
    }, 100);

    function enable(){
        // height of area at the top at bottom, that don't respond to mousemove
        var inactiveMargin = 99;                    
        // Cache for performance
        var wrapperWidth = wrapper.width();
        var wrapperHeight = wrapper.height();
        // Using outer height to include padding too
        var scrollableHeight = scrollable.outerHeight() + 2*inactiveMargin;
        // Do not cache wrapperOffset, because it can change when user resizes window
        // We could use onresize event, but it's just not worth doing that 
        // var wrapperOffset = wrapper.offset();

        // Create a invisible tooltip
        var tooltip = $('<div class="sc_menu_tooltip"></div>')
            .css('opacity', 0)
            .appendTo(wrapper);

        // Save menu titles
        scrollable.find('a').each(function(){               
            $(this).data('tooltipText', this.title);                
        });

        // Remove default tooltip
        scrollable.find('a').removeAttr('title');       
        // Remove default tooltip in IE
        scrollable.find('img').removeAttr('alt');   

        var lastTarget;
        //When user move mouse over menu            
        wrapper.mousemove(function(e){
            // Save target
            lastTarget = e.target;

            var wrapperOffset = wrapper.offset();

            var tooltipLeft = e.pageX - wrapperOffset.left;
            // Do not let tooltip to move out of menu.
            // Because overflow is set to hidden, we will not be able too see it 
            tooltipLeft = Math.min(tooltipLeft, wrapperWidth - 75); //tooltip.outerWidth());

            var tooltipTop = e.pageY - wrapperOffset.top + wrapper.scrollTop() - 40;
            // Move tooltip under the mouse when we are in the higher part of the menu
            if (e.pageY - wrapperOffset.top < wrapperHeight/2){
                tooltipTop += 80;
            }               
            tooltip.css({top: tooltipTop, left: tooltipLeft});              

            // Scroll menu
            var top = (e.pageY -  wrapperOffset.top) * (scrollableHeight - wrapperHeight) / wrapperHeight - inactiveMargin;
            if (top < 0){
                top = 0;
            }           
            wrapper.scrollTop(top);
        });

        // Setting interval helps solving perfomance problems in IE
        var interval = setInterval(function(){
            if (!lastTarget) return;    

            var currentText = tooltip.text();

            if (lastTarget.nodeName == 'IMG'){                  
                // We've attached data to a link, not image
                var newText = $(lastTarget).parent().data('tooltipText');

                // Show tooltip with the new text
                if (currentText != newText) {
                    tooltip
                        .stop(true)
                        .css('opacity', 0)  
                        .text(newText)
                        .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
                }                   
            }
        }, 200);

        // Hide tooltip when leaving menu
        wrapper.mouseleave(function(){
            lastTarget = false;
            tooltip.stop(true).css('opacity', 0).text('');
        });         

        /*
        //Usage of hover event resulted in performance problems
        scrollable.find('a').hover(function(){
            tooltip
                .stop()
                .css('opacity', 0)
                .text($(this).data('tooltipText'))
                .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);

        }, function(){
            tooltip
                .stop()
                .animate({opacity: 0}, 300);
        });
        */          
    }
}

$(function(){   
    makeScrollable("div.sc_menu_wrapper", "div.sc_menu");
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="overflow: hidden;" class="sc_menu_wrapper">
    <div style="display: block;" class="sc_menu">
        <a href="#" ><img src="images/1.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#" ><img src="images/2.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#" ><img src="images/3.jpg"></a>       
        <a href="#" ><img src="images/4.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#" ><img src="images/5.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#" ><img src="images/6.jpg"></a>

    </div>
<div style="display: none;" class="loading">Loading...</div><div style="opacity: 0;" class="sc_menu_tooltip"></div></div>

</body></html>
</php>
```

Comment: What are `<php>` and `</php>`?

Comment: it just to make sure that it is a php files.is it really the problem?

Comment: As you are already using jQuery, you can reduce your javascript to about 2 lines...

Comment: What are the contents of the 7.php file?

Comment: @biksupahai: Probably not, but you shouldn't be using them.  Those are not valid HTML nor PHP tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="javascript:ajaxpage('ajaxfiles/hotel.html', 'rightcolumn'); loadobjs('css/style.css', 'css/slide.css', 'js/jquery1.3.2-min.js', 'js/jquery-ui1.5.3-min.js', 'js/featured.js')">See Hotel</a>
```

This code will work...